# Conditionally causing a full postback on a button in an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to cause a full postback on a button, conditionally, that is within an UpdatePanel?

The reason for this is that 1) The page is dynamically built and it is a control, so I can't use the  collection of the update panel, and 2) I will only be doing a full postback under certain situations.

The "certain situations" will be evaluated by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a postbacktrigger to the updatepanel with the controlid of the button? Thats the best way to do it.

If you want to programmatically add the trigger depending on certain conditions, you can do this while rendering the page.

```
    PostBackTrigger t = new PostBackTrigger();
    t.ControlID = btn.ClientID;
    updatePanel1.Triggers.Add(t);
```

Comment: As I said, this is happening in a control that has the contents dynamically built and I will not always be requiring a full post back. I said "Is it possible to cause a full postback on a button, conditionally, that is within an UpdatePanel?" Not that I always want to do a postback.

Comment: Yeah, so why don't you add the trigger programatically? Updating my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: I'd thought of that. You still aren't reading my question. It needs to be conditional based on JavaScript logic.

Comment: okay this wont work if it is based on javascript logic, but to be fair you din't mention that :).

Comment: Ahh sorry - my bad. Will update and expand upon the "under certain situations".